# Find a parametrization for the curve $x^2-y=2$ for $x \in [0,1]$

Tags: calculus, integration

Find a parametrization for the curve $x^2-y=2$ for $x \in [0,1]$

---

I suspect that this ought to be quite easy, but I'm not sure how to go about the parametrization when we have a specified domain of a variable. Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Given a function $f(x)$ the parameterization $(t,f(t))$ always works. Can you see how that's useful here?

Comment: In brief: make the variable $x$ the parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rearranging we get

$$y=x^2-2,$$

and so the curve is the graph of the function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ given by

$$f(x)=x^2-2.$$

A function graph can always be parameterized by $t\mapsto(t,f(t))$, and so a parameterization of the curve is given by

$$\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R},\quad t\mapsto (t,t^2-2).$$

Comment: $y=x^2+2$, little error but reasoning is correct.

Comment: @ryaron No, you're wrong, it is $y=x^2-2$. Look at the original equation again.

Comment: sorry, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

$y=x^2+2$

$\phi=(t, t^2+2),\;t\in[0,1]$

and in arclength parametrization:

$ds=\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2}dt=(1+4t^2)dt$

Typo:
$y=x^2-2$

So the parametrization is:

$\phi(t)=(t, t^2-2)$

Arclength parametrization stays.

Comment: It should be $y=x^2-2$

Comment: Thanks for the correction it has been mentioned in the answer.